# Create installer to copy my Dlls to Program Files

Tags: windows-installer, dllregistration

I want to create a simple MSI to install some DLLs into programs, similar to how Telerik installs itself.

Telerik uses "C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for WPF Q1 2009\Binaries\WPF\"

I'd like to do something simiar, such as "C:\Program Files\Foo\Bar\Bin\"

Is this just as simple as creating an Installer project, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an installer is a task that has many pitfalls. You should take a look at using [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which is an installer generator that helps you avoid many of them.